# $X$ complete normed space $\implies\mathrm B(X,Y)$ complete normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbf N}\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant}\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant} 
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$I was looking through the functional analysis notes of TWK (on his webpage https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/) and was trying to answer the following question: If $X$ is a complete normed space and $Y$ is a normed space, is $\mathrm B(X,Y)$ complete? ($\mathrm B(X,Y)$ is the normed space of bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$, with as norm the operator norm).
It seems to me that this is not the case, and I have thought of (what I think is) a counterexample. I'm not completely sure about the last step I made and therefore would like to ask you to verify that it is correct, show me how to correct it, or tell me that my counterexample is wrong and why.

**Claim** If $X$ is a complete normed space and $Y$ a normed space, $\mathrm B(X,Y)$ is not necessarily complete:

**Proof** Consider $X=\ell^\infty(\N),Y=c_{00}(\N)$ ($c_{00}(\N)$ is the set of sequences of compact support), with the norm on $Y$ the $\ell^1$ norm. Let, for $n\in\N_{\geq 1}$, $T_n:X\to Y$ be given by 
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots)\mapsto\left(\frac{x_1}{1^2},\frac{x_2}{2^2},\frac{x_3}{3^2},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{n^2},0,0,\ldots\right)$$
For every $n\in \N_{\geq 1}$, $T_n$ is linear. Furthermore each $T_n$ is bounded: Let $x=(x_n)\in X$. Then $\|x\|=\sup|x_n|<\infty$. So 
$$\|T_nx\|=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{|x_k|}{k^2}\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{\sup|x_n|}{k^2}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\|x\|\leq\frac{\pi^2}{6}\|x\|$$
We conclude that for all $n\in\N_{\geq 1}, T_n\in \mathrm B(X,Y)$, because
$$\|T_n\|\leq \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Furthermore $(T_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathrm B(X,Y)$: Let $\eps>0$. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges, so there is an $N\in\N$ such that $\forall m,n\geq N$ we have $\sum_{k=m}^n \frac{1}{k^2}=\left|\sum_{k=m}^n \frac{1}{k^2}\right|<\frac{\eps}{2}$. Now let $x=(x_n)\in X$. Then $\|x\|=\sup |x_n|<\infty$ so for $m,n\geq N$ (wlog we assume $m<n$), we have
$$\|(T_n-T_m)x\|=\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^n\frac{|x_k|}{k^2}\leq\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^n \frac{\sup|x_n|}{k^2}<\frac{\eps}{2}\|x\|$$
And from this it follows that for $m,n\geq N$ 
$$\|T_n-T_m\|\leq \frac{\eps}{2}<\eps$$
Finally, $(T_n)$ does not converge: This is the step that I'm not completely sure about. My idea is as follows

We have $\mathrm B(X,\ell^1(\N))\supset \mathrm B(X,Y)$. $\mathrm B(X,\ell^1(\N))$ is complete (because $\ell^1(\N)$ is complete) and $(T_n)$ is also a Cauchy sequence in $\mathrm B(X,\ell^1(\N))$ and so it converges to a $T\in \mathrm B(X,\ell^1(\N))$. In fact we can give $T$ explicitly, for $x=(x_n)\in\ell^\infty(\N)$ we have $(Tx)_n=\frac{x_n}{n^2}$ for each $n\in\N_{\geq 1}$. Now it is clear that $T$ does not map $\ell^\infty(\N)$ into $c_{00}(\N)$ (consider the sequence with all entries equal to $1$ and what it gets mapped to) and so $T\not\in \mathrm B(X,Y)$. If $(T_n)$ would converge in $\mathrm B(X,Y)$ then it would converge to the same limit in $\mathrm B(X,\ell^1(\N))$ (because we consider $\mathrm B(X,Y)$ as a metric subspace of $\mathrm B(X,\ell^1(\N))$) so by uniqueness of limits in $\mathrm B(X,\ell^1(\N))$ we conclude that $(T_n)$ does not converge in $\mathrm B(X,Y)$.

This shows that $X$ being a complete normed space does not necessarily imply that $\mathrm B(X,Y)$ is complete.

Comment: It's correct. You could even shorten it by noting that $B(X,Y)$ is not closed as a subspace of $B(X,\ell^!(\mathbb{N}))$ (after you say $T\not\in B(X,Y)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can significantly simplify your proof, take $X=\mathbb{R}$ while $Y$ is any non complete. Obviously $Y$ is complete iff so does $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$.

Comment: Sorry to bother you about an old question, but it is not clear to me why $I$ being isometric would imply that $\mathrm{im}( I)$ is closed in $B(X,Y)$ (consider for instance the inclusion of an incomplete normed space in its completion). Is there some additional reasoning missing that applies in this specific case?

Comment: Well, that was erroneous argument. Now I suggest  even more simpler example.

Comment: I'm not sure how $Y$ is obviously complete iff $B(X,Y)$ is. One implication is clear ($Y$ complete $\implies$ $B(X,Y)$ complete), but I am not sure how I would prove the other implication.

Comment: Any opertator in $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is of the form $T(z)=z y$ for some $y\in Y$. Consider Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ with no limit. It induces a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ with no limit.

Comment: Oh I didn't take into account that you had set $X=\mathbf R$. I'm still curious about the situation when $X$ is a general normed space and in an answer to the linked question you refer the reader to this answer for the proof that $Y$ not complete $\implies$ $B(X,Y)$ not complete (for a general normed space $X$). I am wondering if your previous argument can be salvaged.

Comment: I don't know. But the implication you are talking about is valid for all nonzer Banach space X. I've seen this proof in several functional analysis books, but I don't remember the unit xac reference.