# Prove that the space of continuous linear functionals B(X,Y) is complete iff Y is complete

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces and assume that $X\ne\{0\}$. Prove that $B(X,Y)$ - space of continuous linear functionals $A:X\rightarrow Y$ - is complete with respect to the norm $\|A\|:=\sup_{\|x\|\le1}{\|Ax\|}$ **iff** $Y$ is complete.

**My attempt:**

"$\implies$"

Let $(A_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence of functionals from $B(X,Y)$. We have that
$$\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_{N>0}\forall_{n,m>N} \sup_{\|x\|\le1}{\|(A_n-A_m)x\|} <\epsilon$$
and
$$\exists A\in B(X,Y) : \sup_{\|x\|\le1}{\|(A_n-A)x\|} \rightarrow 0$$

I notice that $\|(A_n-A_m)x\|\le\sup_{\|x\|\le1}{\|(A_n-A_m)x\|}$ when $\|x\|\le1$ and therefore $(A_nx)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ when $\|x\|\le1$. I don't know how can I move from this point. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would say that you are starting from the wrong place. To prove that $Y$ is complete, when $B(X,Y)$ is. Start with a Cauchy Sequence $(a_n) \in Y$. Show that if $(a_n)$ does not converge, then you can build a sequence of linear functionals that form a cauchy sequence under the norm and cannot converge.

Comment: ok, I will try and reedit. Please don't post full answer yet. I'd like to try by myself first :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/131829/19538) for the proof $Y$ is complete$\implies$$\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is complete

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750654/x-complete-normed-space-implies-mathrm-bx-y-complete-normed-space) for the proof $Y$ is not complete$\implies$ $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is not complete

Answer (score 2):

It's a little surprising to find this question remain unanswered, so although the original poster must have lost use of it, for the sake of completeness here's a partial one following the book Functional Analysis by B.V. Limaye (Third edition 2014, New Age International Publishers).

Fix a non-zero element $ f \in X^* $ and an ${\mathbf x}_0 \in \mathbf X $ where $f$ does not vanish. Given a Cauchy sequence $({\mathbf y}_n )$ in $\mathbf Y$, define $ T_n: \mathbf X \to \mathbf Y $ by $ T_n (\mathbf x) = f(\mathbf x) \cdot \mathbf y_n $.

Now argue that $(T_n)$ is Cauchy in $ \mathbf B (\mathbf X, \mathbf Y) $, call the limit $T$ and conclude that $ \mathbf y_n = T_n (\mathbf x_0) / f(\mathbf x_0) \to T (\mathbf x_0) / f(\mathbf x_0) $ in $\mathbf Y $ as $ n \to \infty $.

Comment: This construction is interesting! For the completeness, the first sentence of the argument "Fix a non-zero element f∈X∗
 and an x0∈X
 where f
 does not vanish. " need to use Hahn-Banach Theorem for construction.